# Which programming languages can I use on Android Dalvik?

Tags: java, python, android, scala, dalvik

In theory, Dalvik executes any virtual machine byte code, created for example with the compilers of

- AspectJ
- ColdFusion
- Clojure
- Groovy
- JavaFX Script
- JRuby
- Jython
- Rhino
- Scala

Are there already working versions of bytecode compilers for Dalvik available for other languages than Java?

Comment: The fact that Dalvik executes a form of bytecode compiled from Java source does not imply that it is JVM compatible, even "in theory".

Comment: Note ‘Rhino’ is an implementation of ‘JavaScript’, ‘Jython’ an implementation of ‘Python’. [Click here for a more complete list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages#JVM_languages). Also **HTML** and **JavaScript** languages can be used in a `WebView` on Android and there are even JavaScript frameworks and SDKs.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

- At launch, `Java` was the only officially supported programming language for building distributable third-party Android software.
- Android Native Development Kit (Android NDK) which will allow developers to build Android software components with `C` and `C++`.
- In addition to delivering support for native code, Google is also extending Android to support popular **dynamic scripting languages**. Earlier this month, Google launched  the  **[Android Scripting Environment (ASE)](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)**  which allows third-party developers to build simple Android applications with `perl`, `JRuby`, `Python`, `LUA` and `BeanShell`. For having idea and usage of **ASE**, refer this [***Example link***](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-android-scripting.html).
- [Scala](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Developing_for_Android)  is also supported. For having examples of Scala, refer these  [**Example link-1**](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/219) ,   [**Example link-2**](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/steps.html) ,  [**Example link-3**](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/wikla/OTS/Sisalto/examples/) .
- Just now i have referred one  ***[Article Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73089/Comparison-of-Android-vs-iPhone-vs-Nokia-vs-BlackB.aspx)***  in which i found some useful information as follows:

  1. programming language is Java but bridges from other languages exist `(C# .net - Mono, etc)`.
  2. can run script languages like `LUA`, `Perl`, `Python`, `BeanShell`, etc.
- I have read 2nd article at [Google Releases 'Simple' Android Programming Language](http://www.informationweek.com/news/internet/google/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=218700186) . For example of this, [refer this](http://simplecompiler.blogspot.com/) .
- Just now (2 Aug 2010) i have read an article which describes regarding "**Frink Programming language and Calculating Tool for Android**", refer this links  [**Link-1**](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/frink-programming-language_fbiv.html) ,  [**Link-2**](http://futureboy.homeip.net/frinkdocs/android.html)
- On 4-Aug-2010, i have found Regarding ***`RenderScript`***. Basically, It is said to be a C-like language for high performance graphics programming, which helps you easily write efficient Visual effects and animations in your Android Applications. Its not released yet as it isn't finished.

Answer (score 25):

Scala works very well.

I'm programming my Android application projects in Scala ([Website written in Chinese with some screenshot](http://bone.twbbs.org.tw/maidroid/MaidroidReminder), [source code @ GitHub](http://github.com/brianhsu/Maidroid/tree/master/MaidroidReminder/)), and it is pretty easy to setup the evnviroment (without IDE, using SBT as build tool).

It could access every API in Android SDK, so anything you could do in Java, you could do it in Scala too.

You may check this [blog entry](http://zegoggl.es/2009/12/building-android-apps-in-scala-with-sbt.html) to see how to build Android application with Scala and SBT.

Answer (score 8):

[Kawa](http://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/) is a lovely but little known variant of Scheme that has existed quietly for many years and runs on both the JVM and Dalvik, *natively*.  Therefore, its output includes no extra VM and only includes explicitly imported libraries.  To the end-programmer, this means Kawa's performance and executable size are nearly identical to standard Java (ProGuard not required).

Kawa also includes lots of macros (including some specific to Android APIs) that make for a nice clean syntax (assuming one is not averse to parentheses), and adds some tasty goodies on top of Scheme, like "promises" (lazy eval and futures in one).  The language is quite robust and well-documented, and has been actively maintained and evolving since the early days of Java.

[The Java Advent Calendar](http://www.javaadvent.com/2012/12/kawa-oldest-functional-language-on-jvm.html) summarizes Kawa's merits with some informative examples and links.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't played with it but I know that Scala works.

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/160

Answer (score 3):

Another JVM language that works on Android is [Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/) with [Anko](https://github.com/JetBrains/anko), both from [Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[Mercury](http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/index.html) also works on Android, using its Java backend.  I've written a [simple app](https://github.com/ayrnieu/InquisitorM/) that should help someone get started (there are still few other examples), and [mercury-android-helper](https://github.com/ayrnieu/mercury-android-helper) also for this purpose (although at this exact moment, it's short a few commits.  And neither are using ProGuard yet, so the `.apk` size is shocking.)

Although the other posts here are cheerful about Scala-on-Android, posters in Scala forums are more concerned by Scala's ability to blow through some of Dalvik's limitations, and people who do use it say they reserve it for non-production code.  (Some discussion about Scala's problems [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/El3QZEbIwHg).)

I can't say yet if Mercury has its own problems with Dalvik, but I've switched to it from Scala for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamically typed languages wont be possible until Dalvik supports JIT (Just In Time) compiling. I believe there is JIT support in one of the experimental Eclair branches, but it is not yet officially available/supported in Android.

Comment: No, even with Android Froyo's JIT, most dynamic languages will not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973386/android-adverse-to-dynamic-languages

Answer (score 0):

1) Angular + nativeScript

2) Reactnative