# Which programming languages can be used to develop in Android?

Tags: java, android, scala, programming-languages, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which programming languages can I use on Android Dalvik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994703/which-programming-languages-can-i-use-on-android-dalvik)

Mostly, Android applications are written in Java. But i heard that its also possible to use Scala or some other languages. And I also read that it's possible to include native C/C++ code.

Is there a refernce/list available that shows which languages can be used?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994703/which-programming-languages-can-i-use-on-android-dalvik

Comment: See: <http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html#overview>

Comment: @mjustin  - that's related, but NOT a duplicate. It *only* refers to the dalvik VM, rather than native development with C++/C

Comment: then overthere nobody has mentioned regarding ASE(Android scripting Environment)...i also dont understand the close votes.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

- At launch, `Java` was the only officially supported programming language for building distributable third-party Android software.
- Android Native Development Kit (Android NDK) which will allow developers to build Android software components with `C` and `C++`.
- In addition to delivering support for native code, Google is also extending Android to support popular **dynamic scripting languages**. Earlier this month, Google launched  the  **[Android Scripting Environment (ASE)](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)**  which allows third-party developers to build simple Android applications with `perl`, `JRuby`, `Python`, `LUA` and `BeanShell`. For having idea and usage of ASE, refer this [***Example link***](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-android-scripting.html).
- [Scala](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Developing_for_Android)  is also supported. For having examples of Scala, refer these  [**Example link-1**](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/219) ,   [**Example link-2**](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/steps.html) ,  [**Example link-3**](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/wikla/OTS/Sisalto/examples/) .
- Just now i have referred one  ***[Article Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73089/Comparison-of-Android-vs-iPhone-vs-Nokia-vs-BlackB.aspx)***  in which i found some useful information as follows:

  1. programming language is Java but bridges from other languages exist `(C# .net - Mono, etc)`.
  2. can run script languages like `LUA`, `Perl`, `Python`, `BeanShell`, etc.
- I have read 2nd article at [Google Releases 'Simple' Android Programming Language](http://www.informationweek.com/news/internet/google/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=218700186) . For example of this, [refer this](http://simplecompiler.blogspot.com/) .
- Just now (2 Aug 2010) i have read an article which describes regarding "**Frink Programming language and Calculating Tool for Android**", refer this links  [**Link-1**](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/frink-programming-language_fbiv.html) ,  [**Link-2**](http://futureboy.homeip.net/frinkdocs/android.html)
- On 4-Aug-2010, i have found Regarding **`RenderScript`**. Basically, It is said to be a C-like language for high performance graphics programming, which helps you easily write efficient Visual effects and animations in your Android Applications. Its not released yet as it isn't finished.

Comment: checkout..i have added new example links for scala

Comment: Checkout..i have added "frink Prog. for Android" detail

Comment: For having video regarding "Android Scripting Environment"....refer this links : http://www.slideshare.net/gasolin/introduction-of-android-scripting-environment

Comment: On 4-aug-2010, i have added detail regarding "RenderScript for Android" detail

Answer (score 53):

Here's a list of languages that can be used to develop on android:

- Java - primary android development language
- [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), language from JetBrains which received first-party support from Google, announced in Google I/O 2017
- C++ - [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) for libraries, not apps
- Python, bash, et. al. - Via the [Scripting Environment](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting)
- [Corona](http://coronalabs.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started-with-corona/)- One is to use the  [Corona SDK](http://coronalabs.com/) . Corona is a high level SDK built on the Lua programming language. Lua is much simpler to learn than Java and the SDK takes away a lot of the pain in developing Android app.
- [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) - which uses HTML5, JavaScript, CSS, and can be extended with Java
- [Xamarin technology](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/) - that uses c# and in which mono is used for that. Here MonoTouch and Mono for Android are cross-platform implementations of the Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) and Common Language Specifications.

As for your second question: android is highly dependent on it's java architecture, I find it unlikely that there will be other primary development languages available any time soon. However, there's no particular reason why someone couldn't implement another language *in Java* (something like Jython) and use that. However, that surely won't be easier or as performant as just writing the code in Java.

Comment: Another info was missing just for the record, if someone do not need hardware access simply they can do quick HTML/CSS/JavaScript apps to save some time for small apps. e.g: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc5xxN-awuE

Comment: "...as performant as Java..." sad to see that this sentence (as correct as it is in this case) exists

Comment: @Mark - "as performant as Java code running in the DalvikVM on a device designed to run Java code running in the DalvikVM." ... This comment wasn't intended to endorse Java as a programming language or to make general claims as to the performance or readability of said language. :)

Comment: Kotlin from Jetbrains : https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin

Comment: You forgot Chrome Progressive Web Apps https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/desktop

Answer (score 9):

Scala is [supported](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Developing_for_Android). See [example](http://zegoggl.es/2009/12/building-android-apps-in-scala-with-sbt.html).

Support for other languages is [problematic](http://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/with_android_and_dalvik_at):

> 7) Something like the dx tool can be forced into the phone, so that Java code could in principle continue to generate bytecodes, yet have them be translated into a VM-runnable form. But, at present, Java code cannot be generated on the fly. This means Dalvik cannot run dynamic languages (JRuby, Jython, Groovy). Yet. (Perhaps the dex format needs a detuned variant which can be easily generated from bytecodes.)

Comment: It's not so problematic anymore: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 4):

As stated above, many languages are available for developing in Android. Java, C, Scala, C++, several scripting languages etc. Thanks to Mono you are also able to develop using C# and the .Net framework. Here you have some speedcomparisions: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=It8xPqkKxis

Comment: Keep in mind that these comparisons are made using Android 1.5. Android 2.2 includes a JIT compiler that claims to improve the performance of Dalwin by 2-5x.

Comment: That video is private :-\

Answer (score 3):

[Clojure](http://www.clojure.org) can be used, but it's slow.

See also: [Clojure fork for Android](http://github.com/remvee/clj-android/), and a [tutorial](http://riddell.us/ClojureAndAndroidWithEmacsOnUbuntu.html).

Answer (score 3):

I made good experiences with Scala.

I use the simple build tool (sbt: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/) with the Android-Plugin (http://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Java and C:

- C used for low level functionalities and device connectivities
- Java used for Framework and Application Level

You may find more information in Android developers site.