# What programming languages can one use to develop Android applications?

Tags: android, programming-languages, mobile

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Which programming languages can I use on Android Dalvik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994703/which-programming-languages-can-i-use-on-android-dalvik)
>   [Which programming languages can be used to develop in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316801/which-programming-languages-can-be-used-to-develop-in-android)

What programming languages can one use to develop Android applications?

Are there plans in the future to expand the amount of programming languages that Android will support?