# Javascript/HTML/CSS for Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

For developing applications in Android, do we need knowledge of Javascript/HTML/CSS ?
Or it is entirely possible to develop a complete Android application using only Java ?

Comment: Did you look at the official documentations ? Did they even mention HTML or CSS or JavaScript ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to know java to develop for android. So: no you don't need the knowledge of Javascript/HTML/CSS for developing apps for android.

If you want to you can make a web app: 
[http://www.amazon.com/Building-Android-Apps-HTML-JavaScript/dp/1449316417](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449316417) 
That is a book which can maybe help you.

[What programming languages can one use to develop Android applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949980/what-programming-languages-can-one-use-to-develop-android-applications)

In that question the best answer says the languages you can use to develop for Android.