# Python as Android build requirement

Tags: android, python

Heres the official link for Android source code build/development.

http://source.android.com/source/building.html

As you can see one of the prerequisites is setting up Python.

From what I have heard/read, only Java is primarily used for Android app development..so why the need for Python ?.

Can you point out what I am obviously missing ?

*** This is a newbie question ***

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949980/what-programming-languages-can-one-use-to-develop-android-applications

Comment: Since Google supports Python so much, it's really no surprise that they like using it for Android. :)

Comment: Just so we're clear, you do understand that the link you've given is for development of the Android **operating system** itself, not apps for Android phones?

Comment: http://www.kivy.org Awesome Python library used for developing Android apps :)

Comment: To follow your logic, if you have Java then why would you use Python *anywhere*?  To answer that question, take a look at some Java code then look at some Python code which does the same thing.  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Languages is one place to start comparing programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the target device is running Java based virtual machine, the SDK build scripts may leverage Python.

Thus, Python is required to *build* Android software or SDK, but Python itself is not run on the device.

Likewise, you need *git* even though you surely won't run version control system on your phone.