# What language should I use to make a simple android app that can be used to save homework

Tags: android

I want to make an android app that I will use instead of a homework diary, and I am trying to figure out what language to use. I want to be able to open the app and input my homework, and then at the end of the day, I can open it again, and review all the homework that I entered that day, until I press a button to reset. I want it to have the following specifications:

1. Buttons for each subject
2. Pressing the button opens another page where I can input the homework
3. The homework must be saved, even when the app is closed.
4. The homework can be reset by pressing a button.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java, it is the main language for Android apps developpment.

More detailled answer here :

[What programming languages can one use to develop Android applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949980/what-programming-languages-can-one-use-to-develop-android-applications)