# what programming languages does 2.2 officially support?

Tags: android, programming-languages, android-2.2-froyo

I know you can write apps in c, c++, and java. However I have heard that android also supports scheme, python, lua, and others but never could find it verified or an actual list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994703/which-programming-languages-can-i-use-on-android-dalvik

Comment: and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316801/which-programming-languages-can-be-used-to-develop-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Here are some that I use on my (unrooted) 2.2 and 2.3 phones (plus pForth from the command line)

Market compilers and interpreters:

- BASIC!+SQL

  Light Basic

  CalcScipt (RPN)

  Clojure REPL

  Android Shell (Beanshell)

  JavaIDEdroid (Java)

  Andjedi (Java)

  Terminal IDE (Java)

  AIDL (Java)

  aDosBox (DOS languages via emulation)

  Android Logo

  Gambit (Scheme)

  GCC and G++ (via command line)

  Tiny C Compiler

  SpiderMonkey (command line javascript)

  Generate (javascript based graphical)

  Processing (javascript based)

  cat (javascript based functional RPN)

  Graphicalc (C interp)

  IProgram (Basic like)

  JoyToy (Basic like)

  Tiny Lisp ISLisproid

  Luarida (Lua)

  Mathscript

  Mobile BASIC

  Mobile Futon (couchdb+javascript server)

  OCaml toplevel for Android

  Pascal

  Pepe (Pascal compiler)

  Retro (javascript based Forth-like)

  Rubuto IRB (jRuby)

  SchemeREPL

  Scheme-droid

  Sharpoid (javascript based)

  Sigmascript (Lua)

  C# to go

  ScriptBlocks (visual,symPy based)

  i-Jetty (servlets using one of the Java compiler systems above)

The languages presently supported by SL4A are Beanshell, Rhino javascript, jRuby, perl,TCL, PHP, Python, ash, Lua, squirrel.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are referring to the scripting layer for Android, here is what the [Scripting Layer for Android site](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) says about supported languages:

"Python, Perl, JRuby, Lua, BeanShell, JavaScript, Tcl, and shell are currently supported, and we're planning to add more."

Answer (score -1):

Officially, no

Unofficially, Scala, Scheme and others have modified runtimes and compilers to work on android. Those that compile/translate directly to dex opcodes without too big of 3rd party lib contained in the apk are of course better performance wise.

Comment: There is official support for python, lua, and several other languages.

Comment: not from Google sir..and that is the measure of official for this question