# How can you implement android apps without android?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which programming languages can I use on Android Dalvik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994703/which-programming-languages-can-i-use-on-android-dalvik)
>   [Which programming languages can be used to develop in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316801/which-programming-languages-can-be-used-to-develop-in-android)

Are there any alternatives for building apps for Android devices without programming in android? Maybe Python or something like that?

Comment: duplicate of [Which programming languages can be used to develop in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316801/which-programming-languages-can-be-used-to-develop-in-android) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949980/what-programming-languages-can-one-use-to-develop-android-applications and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742248/development-languages-for-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182024/what-programming-languages-does-2-2-officially-support and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994703/which-programming-languages-can-i-use-on-android-dalvik and many others

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap is a good alternative that would allow you to use html, css and javascript to develop applications for any mobile platform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  See [Scripting Layer for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/).