# Development Languages For Android

Tags: java, android, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which programming languages can I use on Android Dalvik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994703/which-programming-languages-can-i-use-on-android-dalvik)

I was a Java developer for 3 years, now I want to retire my Java skills for some time and go to some other languages(I already develop in more than 8 languages) that can be used for Android development and their tools/IDEs.

*PS: I need tools/languages that I can build APKs that I can distribute at the Market using my account there*

Comment: If you know java, why would you want to use something other than java for android?

Comment: I wasn't thinking about languages that use Java(like Scala). So please reopen the question

Answer (score 1):

I was like you and was interested in Scala. I have a tab folder fall of useful links.

http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=android+scala+eclipse&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

http://tiliman.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/android-development-with-scala/

http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Developing_for_Android

http://code.google.com/p/scala-android/downloads/list

[Scala Programming for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476111/scala-programming-for-android)

https://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin/wiki

http://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin

http://chneukirchen.org/blog/archive/2009/04/programming-for-android-with-scala.html

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I don't want Scala, I was thinking on something distant from Java

Comment: @Nathan - If it's so distant from Java that it doesn't run on Dalvik, you're making pain for yourself trying to use it for Android development.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is an option (seriously!) if you want to build a mobile web-based app, and then distribute it in a PhoneGap native wrapper.