# Clojure on Android

Tags: android, clojure

Is it possible to program Android apps in Clojure?
Can anybody suggest a good tutorial or book, if it is possible?

Answer (score 29):

Yes, here is main project I am aware of: https://github.com/remvee/clojurehelloandroid

And here is a little tutorial http://riddell.us/ClojureAndAndroidWithEmacsOnUbuntu.html though I would not be surprised if this tutorial is outdated, as it was over a year ago when I played with the code following this tutorial, and remvee's code has since been updated.

EDIT: see the update here from Stuart Sierra and the Clojure/core group: http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/876c90d3ae353c61

> "Clojure 1.2.0 works "out of the box"
>   on Android, but startup time is still
>   a problem. Some members of
>   Clojure/core have experimented with
>   ways to make this better, mostly by
>   selectively removing stuff that isn't
>   needed at runtime.
>
> Follow
>   http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Android+Support
>   for news. The last update was by Aaron
>   Bedra, a Clojure/core member, in
>   December 2010. I wouldn't say it's a
>   high priority right now, but neither
>   have people lost interest.
>
> I personally would not recommend
>   writing an Android app in Clojure if
>   you intend to release it right away.
>   But if you're interested experimenting
>   with Clojure on Android and making it
>   better, then go for it."

Answer (score 17):

Clojure benefits greatly from the android 2.2 JIT compiler which greatly improves class load times. Clojure creates lots of small classes which was taking 'forever' to load on previous android versions.

check out this 'in progress' work on a [swank plugin](https://github.com/exterm/swank-android-builder) for androiding with clojure

Comment: heh, I thought 'swank' here was just another adjective.

Comment: I see, I will attempt to find where this moved to. Pretty cool 404 though :)

Answer (score 14):

A new option for Clojure on android is [ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript).

ClojureScript compiles Clojure into JavaScript which you can then wrap in 
an app. This bypasses the Dalvik-VM entirely and avoids the load time issues,
if your app is suited to javascript. many apps looking for more tight 
integration with the platform can't use this approach. If your app 
can live with out tight platform integration this could save you a lot of
time.

Comment: it's too bad you can't script the java with clojurescript

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a bit old, but just in case someone stumbles on this, clojure on Android has come a long way since the answers above. The [lein-droid](https://github.com/clojure-android/lein-droid) and the [Neko](https://github.com/clojure-android/neko) projects do make it a lot easier to write full android programs using clojure from begining to end.

Answer (score 7):

This has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973386/android-adverse-to-dynamic-languages). Yes, it is possible with a few minor hacks. However last time I tried it was extremely slow and very memory hungry. This was with Clojure 1.1 and Android 2.1. Things might have been improved since then.

Comment: it does seem that everytime this question gets asked it gets better answers :) (as in the answer is closer to "yes it works" and farther from "it may work someday") perhaps next time it's asked we will get a really 'good' answer

Answer (score 1):

Search for "Clojure REPL", "Clojure" or "Sattvik Software" in Android Market and you will find
an excellent REPL. I've been using it in my XOOM 1 Tablet, first with Android 3 and now with Android 4.0 without any problem.

If you search hard enough you will find programs for Java (Java IDE), Ruby (Ruboto IRB), Python, Lua, Perl, Javascript (SL4J for the last four, also SigmaScript for Lua), ISLisp (tiny-ISLispdroid), OCaml (OCaml Toplevel), Scheme, C, C++, C#, Pascal, Basic and even Forth!

I regret they still don't have one for Scala!

Comment: This question was not as much as "How can I run Clojure code on an Android device" but rather "how can I write android apps in Clojure"