# Is there Android support for Clojure?

Tags: android, clojure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clojure on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651757/clojure-on-android)

Given Java is Android's native language and Clojure is a JVM language, is there any support for writing a program in Clojure and cross compiling it to the Android platform?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sattvik.clojure_repl&hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've voted to close.